# can't receive info from my mySQL database, despite having seen a tutorial doing exactly the same

Tags: javascript, mysql

So i am trying to make a program that reads and writes to a MySQL database, which led me to a youtube tutorial. My problem is that despite going through exactly the same process as the fellow in the tutorial, i end up with an empty server despite what should be popping up. My Code is as follows, which should grab every entry in the applicant_info table in my applicants database, and display it on the localhost:3000 browser. Instead, it displays nothing, which im guessing is because it is unable to fetch the information, but i have no idea why that's the case as again, i have followed a tutorial down to the letter.

```js
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host    : 'localhost',
        user    : 'root',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'applicants'
});

const app = express();

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM applicant_info";
    connection.query(sql, (err, results) =>{
        res.send(results);
    })
});

app.listen('3000', () => {
    console.log('Server running on port 3000');
    connection.connect((err) => {
        if(err) {
        };
        console.log('Database Connected!');
    })
});
```

a sidenote about the code is that i for some reason can't run it with the "throw" command, which is why the 'err' if-statements are currently empty. I hope to dear god that this is not the cause, as i have no idea how to fix it.

Here is a picture of what i receive from my browser: [Image Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlHMD.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have an issue with your require :

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mySQL'
```

it should be :

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
```

so your server does not run, and you have a 404 on the browser.

Once it's fixed, start your server,
and you should see this in the console :

```
Server running on port 3000
Database Connected!
```

you should see your data when going to http://localhost:3000

edit:

added more debug to your code :

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log('get called');
    let sql = "SELECT * FROM applicant_info";
    connection.query(sql, (err, results) =>{
        res.send(results);
    })
});

app.listen('3000', () => {
    connection.connect((err) => {
        if(err) {
          console.log('Database not connected!');
          console.log(err)
        } else {
          console.log('Server running on port 3000');
          console.log('Database Connected!');
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: already fixed it, changed nothing unfortunately. the localhost:3000 is still entirely empty.

Comment: Well then you have an issue somewhere, because your code does indeed work on my side, where are you running the node command ? on WSL ?

Comment: im running the command through the visualstudio code command line.

Comment: and what do you see in the browser ? what is the request status ? 200 / 404 ? i think your browser can't reach your server for some reason, try to add a console.log inside app.get and see if your request goes through

Comment: i've added to the post an image of what it looks like.

Comment: i think your database connection does not work, try to do a console.log(err); inside connection.connect

Comment: in that case, do you have any kind of pointers or code to help me get it working? i am completely lost on making this work, frankly.

Comment: i've added more debug to your code, restart the server and try it out, do you see `Database Connected!` or `Database not connected!` when running node, and do you see `get called` on the console when you go to localhost:3000

Comment: ITS WORKING! a lot of roundabouts i had to take, but thanks chief.

Answer (score -1):

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);//Check connection if ($conn->connect_error) { die("Connection failed: ". $conn->connect_error);}echo "Connected successfully"; check DB is connected or not
```

Comment: this is php not node

Comment: this is for php environment

Comment: yes that's the issue, the question is about nodejs not php